# Распространение программы на Java

Tags: лицензирование

Здравствуйте дамы и господа!
Для нашего университета был разработан комплекс программ для проведения тестирования студентов используя java, php, mysql.
Сейчас у руководства появились идеи по распространению данного комплекса.
Вот сейчас возник вопрос имеет ли право университет на продажу этого ПО или существуют какие либо ограничения.

Comment: А денег на консультацию с юристами у университета не появилось...

Comment: Если всё написано своими силами - никто не запрещает распространять. Если использовались какие-либо сторонние библиотеки - условия распространения зависят от лицензии на каждую конкретную библиотеку.

Comment: Да все-таки нужно будет обратиться к юристам, это будет и быстрее и правильнее, да и надежнее. спасибо